# Laravel AWS Elastic Beanslack deployment error- Out of memory error

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I deployed my Application in AWS Elastic Beanslack. Intially I deployed my application directly in Aws console. After configuring all the things. I zipped my code and upload it in a console. At that time its working perfect.

But now I tried to deploy with cli, its shows error. I put `eb deploy` command

```
Creating application version archive "app-xxxxxxxxx".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2020-03-14 18:51:49    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2020-03-14 18:51:55    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-03-14 18:52:22    ERROR   [Instance: i-xxxxxxxxx] Command failed on instance. Return code: 255 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/GenericRule.php on line 36
    Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 809508864) (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in phar:///opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/GenericRule.php on line 36. 
    Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
    2020-03-14 18:52:22    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
    2020-03-14 18:52:22    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-xxxxxxxxx'. Aborting the operation.
    2020-03-14 18:52:23    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

From Internet I tried these all these things
1) I extended memory in php.ini but still its not working
2) I created ebextensions folder and do some configurations but thats also not working

My guess was Initially I deployed manually, so at that time I zipped with vendor folder also. Now when I tried with cli it wont take vendor folder. Instead of its by using `composer install`
So I think I'm facing this issues due to these things

Please let us know, If any other thing I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploy with ElasticBeanstalk (ELB) we should check Environment. With memory_limit, you can config this in Software tab (Configuration)

Follow:

1. Access the ELB
2. Open to your environment
3. Go to Configuration , then Software tab
4. Find the Memory limit field.
5. Change the value for what you want
6. Redeploy

Answer (score 4):

This is a configuration inside de ElasticBeanstalk Environment.

To increase de memory limit:

1. Access the Elastic Beanstalk section
2. Open to your environment
3. Go to `Configuration` , then `Software`
4. Find the `Memory limit` field. The default value is 1024M.
5. Update the value to what you want
6. Apply the change
7. Redeploy your application

Comment: They have apparently changed the configuration tabs. Do you know where is this configuration now?